# Unable to communicate with the PayPal

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, paypal

I am using Payments Pro (Includes Express Checkout) extension in my magento store. Currently am testing the store in sandbox mode. I have configured merchant account details (merchant email, username, password and signature). But when I try to place an order in my store with Credit card purchase, the system says "Unable to communicate with the PayPal". I googled and found that `SSL` should be disabled, if we run the site in local server or not `SSL` in our live server. I disabled and tested the site, again I am seeing the same error. 
How can I fix this?
Any assistance will be helpful.

Comment: I have the same issue on Magento EE 1.14.1. Some time ago it was working but not now. I get the same error you do even with SSL disabled. Were you able to find a solution?